# Autoincrementar id en angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

tengo esta linea en angular, lo que quiero hacer es que la id se auto incremente dependiendo de cuantas imágenes consuma, aclaro estoy consumiendo un servicio que esta siendo expuesto en json

```
<img id="slide-img-" class="img-item2" src="{{ Our.url }}" alt="{{ Our.alt }}">
```

ejemplo

```
slide-img-1
slide-img-2
slide-img-3
```

Comment: Brother se me ocurren un par de cosas, pero necesito saber si estas utilizando angular o angularjs; lo tienes dentro de un ng-for o ng-rpeat?

Comment: estoy utilizando un ng-for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estas recibiendo los datos en Json te recomiendo que los guardes en un arreglo.

```
   this._apiService.getImagenes().subscribe(data=> {
      for (let i in data) {
        this.lista.push((data[i]));
      }
    }
```

Una vez tengas el arreglo lleno ya podrás iterar sobre estos datos desde tu html, y para mostrar un id incrementable puedes hacer uso de una variable de tipo **index**:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of lista; let id = index">


<th>{{id+1}}</th>
```

El id que se ira incrementando con cada interación. Se le suma uno debido a que empieza en cero.
Espero te sirva, suerte!

Comment: Gracias me sirvio

Comment: Recuerda que StackOverflow es una comunidad destinada a compartir conocimiento. Si la respuesta te sirvió, no olvides marcarla como válida, para pueda servirle a otras personas.